# MVC route error when redirecting from http into https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have MVC app with this .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to redirect all http into htpps so i change .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

but seem i do it wrongly, since the query string which suppose to be blank it became 'index.html.var'. so how can i fix it?

Comment: Is there RewriteEngine On at the start of the .htaccess file?

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to write it on a second snippet, but it already in there.